# can I provide a proxy on nodeJS when connecting to mongodb atlas?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

## ask nodejs and mongodb,

the same code I use on a laptop with a private network, runs smoothly. because it only tests the connection with nodeJS to mongodb atlas.
in the connection office using a browser proxy, so to block like this.
please info to resolve this?

I have confirmed the username and password, my ip is white listed in Atlas Account. to disable white listing i use ip - 0.0.0.0/0,

Full Code.
https://pastebin.com/zJeK8LAb

Error Code.
[image]

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`

server is up. port: 3000
Error: querySrv ESERVFAIL _mongodb._tcp.cluster0-bky5t.mongodb.net
at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (dns.js:202:19) {
  errno: 'ESERVFAIL',
  code: 'ESERVFAIL',
  syscall: 'querySrv',
  hostname: '_mongodb._tcp.cluster0-bky5t.mongodb.net'
}
```

Comment: https://pastebin.com/zJeK8LAb - Says "This is a private paste. If you created this paste, please login to view it"

Comment: sorry, i have open public @ykit9

Comment: What kind of proxy you are using? Please describe more in detail. 
It seems that the problem is in proxy itself rather than in your code.